# Bit-banging a ShifBrite led driver with a PIC

Tags: led, pic, c, bit-bang

I am having problems making communicate a Shiftbrite A6281 led driver with a PIC18F4550. What I am trying to do is to send the RGB values to the driver in order to select the color of the led, but I am not even being able to light it up.

My main problem is that I have never used bit-banging before and I am afraid that a novice error in my code may be causing the problem. (such as port configurations or delays). The goal is to send 32 bits to the driver and then make it load (latch) them, then it should light up the leds.

I am using proteus to simulate the circuit and XC8 as a compiler, here is a screenshot and the code used:

[image]

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000 
#include <p18f4550.h>
#include "config.h"
#include <xc.h>

#define RA0  PORTAbits.RA0
#define RA1  PORTAbits.RA1
#define RA2  PORTAbits.RA2
#define RA3  PORTAbits.RA3
#define RA4  PORTAbits.RA4

#define DATA  PORTBbits.RB0
#define CLOCK  PORTBbits.RB6
#define LATCH  PORTBbits.RB2
#define ENABLE PORTBbits.RB4

#define BLUE  0x3FF00000 
#define GREEN  0x000FFC00 
#define RED  0x000003FF
#define WHITE 0x3FFFFFFF
#define BLACK 0x00000000

typedef unsigned char byte;

void write_color(unsigned long int color)
{
    LATCH = 0;
    CLOCK = 0;   
    ENABLE = 0; // 0 = ON

    for (int i=1; i<33; ++i) { 
        if ((color >> (32 - i)) & 1) DATA = 1;
        else DATA = 0;
        CLOCK = 1; 
        __delay_ms(1);
        CLOCK = 0;           
    }

    LATCH = 1;
    CLOCK = 1; CLOCK = 0;
    __delay_ms(1);
    LATCH = 0;
    // ENABLE = 1; 
}


void main()
{
    ADCON1 = 0xFF;  // digital
    TRISA = 0xFF;
    TRISB = 0x00;   // PORTB pins = output

    while (1) {
        if (RA0 == 1) write_color(BLUE); 
        else if (RA1 == 1) write_color(GREEN); 
        else if (RA2 == 1) write_color(RED); 
        else if (RA3 == 1) write_color(WHITE); 
        else if (RA4 == 1) write_color(BLACK); 
        __delay_ms(1);
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to bit-bang this when the 18F4550 has an SPI interface that can do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found that the main problem was that Proteus was having conflicts with the led driver but I couldn't find how to configure the project by myself in order to fix it. Finally, the thing I have done is to use the empty project my teacher created and now everything is working fine.

Some details I changed:

- **Circuit**: I've connected the resistors at the right side of the buttons (10KOhms)
- **Final code**:

  ```
  void main()
  {

  ADCON1 = 0x0F; // config. digital
  TRISA = 0xFF;
  TRISB = 0x00;
  ENABLE = 1;          
  unsigned long int color;

  color = 1; // default
  while(1) {
      if(RA0 == 1) color=BLUE;
      else if (RA1 == 1) color=GREEN;
      else if (RA2 == 1) color=RED; 
      else if (RA3 == 1) color=WHITE;
      else if (RA4 == 1) color=BLACK;          

      if(color != 1){
          ENABLE = 1;
          int i;
          for(i=0; i<32; i++){
              CLOCK = 0;
              if(((color>>(31-i))&0x00000001) == 0x00000001) DATA = 1;
              else DATA = 0;
              CLOCK = 1; //
          }
          CLOCK= 0;
          LATCH= 1;
          ENABLE=0; // activates the led driver!
          LATCH= 0;
          color=1;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Thanks to all who have spent their time trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with Shiftbrite A6281 led driver but here is what I can think of by looking at the code:

```
void write_color(unsigned long int color)
{
    LATCH = 0;
    CLOCK = 0;   
    ENABLE = 0; // 0 = ON

    for (int i=0; i<32; ++i) { 
        if (((color >> (32 - i)) & 0x01) == 0x01)
          {
              DATA = 1;
          }
        else 
         {
            DATA = 0;
         }
        CLOCK = 1; 
        __delay_ms(1);
        CLOCK = 0;           
    }

    /************* HERE I CHANGED ****************/
    //I am assuming when Latch is set to 1, It accepts value
    LATCH = 1;
    //Send a Clock pulse!
    CLOCK = 1; 
    __delay_ms(1);
    CLOCK = 0;
    LATCH = 0;
    // ENABLE = 1; 
}
```

I would also suggest, if possible, try this circuit on Simulator first and check it!